# Javascript : Function to return distinct values in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array to

```
var table = [
      {
        country:"india",
        b:2
      },
      {
         country:"usa",
        b:33
      },
       {
         country:"australia",
        b:3
      },
       {
         country:"india",
        b:32
      },
       {
         country:"southafrica",
        b:31
      },
       {
         country:"australia",
        b:30
      },
      {
        country:"india",
        b:40
      }
    ];
```

result expected :

```
 var table = [
      {
        country:"india",
        b:2
      },
      {
         country:"usa",
        b:33
      },
       {
         country:"australia",
        b:3
      }, 
       {
         country:"southafrica",
        b:31
      }

    ];
```

My code is :

```
function getUniqueValuesOfKey(array, key){
  return array.reduce(function(carry, item){
    if(item[key] && !~carry.indexOf(item[key])) carry.push(item[key]);
    return carry;
  }, []);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(getUniqueValuesOfKey(table, 'a')));
```

how to get the unique array result based on the country key

Comment: your input has no "a" keys

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,With Array reduce and Filter.Hope It helps

```js
var table = [{
  country: "india",
  b: 2
}, {
  country: "usa",
  b: 33
}, {
  country: "australia",
  b: 3
}, {
  country: "india",
  b: 32
}, {
  country: "southafrica",
  b: 31
}, {
  country: "australia",
  b: 30
}, {
  country: "india",
  b: 40
}];

let result = table.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  if (acc.filter(el => el.country == ele.country).length == 0) {
    acc.push(ele)
  }
  return acc;

}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to get the filtered array:

```js
const data = [ { country:"india", b:2 }, { country:"usa", b:33 }, { country:"australia", b:3 }, { country:"india", b:32 }, { country:"southafrica", b:31 }, { country:"australia", b:30 }, { country:"india", b:40 } ];

const getUniqueData = (arr, names = []) => arr.filter(({ country }) => (
  names.includes(country) ?
  false :
  (names.push(country), true)
));

console.log(getUniqueData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with o(n) time complexity.

```
var table = [{
  country: "india",
  b: 2
}, {
  country: "usa",
  b: 33
}, {
  country: "australia",
  b: 3
}, {
  country: "india",
  b: 32
}, {
  country: "southafrica",
  b: 31
}, {
  country: "australia",
  b: 30
}, {
  country: "india",
  b: 40
}];

let result = [];
const countries = {};

for(let item of table) {
    let {country, b} = item;
    if(!countries[country]) {
        countries[country] = b;
        result.push(item);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with one `for` loop.

```js
const table = [{
country: 'india',
b: 2
}, {
country: 'usa',
b: 33
}, {
country: 'australia',
b: 3
}, {
country: 'india',
b: 32
}, {
country: 'southafrica',
b: 31
}, {
country: 'australia',
b: 30
}, {
country: 'india',
b: 40
}];

const getUniqueArray = (array, tempObj = {}) => {
  const uniqueArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    const element = array[i];
    const { country, b } = element;
    if (!tempObj[country]) {
      tempObj[country] = b;
      uniqueArray.push(element);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArray;
};
const result = getUniqueArray(table);
console.log(result);
```